# Why are there so many versions of the TEA block cipher?

Tags: encryption, tea

Why are there so many types of TEA, for example TEA, XTEA, and XXTEA? What are the differences?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The original algorithm is TEA, which is a very lightweight Feistel cipher. However, its extremely simple key schedule has [two weaknesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm#Properties). The first weakness allows what's called a *related key attack*, which is not an issue if the keys are chosen randomly. The second weakness causes *equivalent keys*. This means that, for TEA, any given key is equivalent to three other keys. This effectively weakens the keyspace from 2<sup>128</sup> to 2<sup>126</sup>, which is bad, but not terrible. This is not normally a major problem unless the cipher is used in ways it shouldn't, [such as for a hash](https://web.archive.org/web/20090416175601/http://www.xbox-linux.org/wiki/17_Mistakes_Microsoft_Made_in_the_Xbox_Security_System#The_TEA_Hash).

XTEA was designed to fix the weaknesses in the original algorithm, in particular by adding a more complex key schedule. However, it was found that XTEA [introduces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA#Cryptanalysis) some related key vulnerabilities of its own and did not meet the intended security target. This lead to *another* revision called XXTEA. However XXTEA is [also vulnerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA#Cryptanalysis), in particular to a chosen-plaintext attack requiring only 2<sup>59</sup> queries (although [the attack is impractical](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12997/54184)). The wide-block variation which avoids the usual downsides of a 64-bit block cipher is [highly vulnerable](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/254) as well, negating yet another benefit of XXTEA. In the end, it turns out that TEA itself is still quite secure as a cipher. It remains secure as long as it is [used correctly](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/16193/54184), i.e. as a block cipher with uniform random and unrelated keys.

Comment: Note: the two XXTEA attacks referred to in the answer are the same. Addition: one of XXTEA's feature is a block size parameter. However the algorithm's reduction in the number of rounds as the block size grows is too aggressive, making it vulnerable to differential cryptanalysis, with an attack for $2^{59}$ chosen plaintexts _when the block is widened from 8 to 212 bytes or more_. I know no published attack for less, and it would require a major advance to break XXTEA with a block size of 8 to 24 bytes, or if it was strengthened by replacing 6 with 12 in the formula for the number of rounds.

Comment: These [three](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-24691-6_30) [published](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10207-008-0059-9) [attacks](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-31410-0_8) on XTEA are for reduced round-versions, and require impractically much work. However these attack break more rounds for XTEA than for TEA, which (beside TEA having been more scrutinized) is reason why I would recommend TEA over XTEA _when equivalent keys are not an issue_.